# The meaning of selectObjId

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to understand what selectObjId is. I have seen a few examples online but what it actually does, I am not very clear on. Could anyone please explain what it does, which language it belongs to AJAX? If possible could i please have an example that prints out the value referenced by selectObjId. Any form of help will be appreciated.

Comment: There's no `selectObjId` function in jQuery, jQuery Mobile, JavaScript, or the standard DOM methods. So it's either part of the code of the project you're working on, or code in some other library. You'll have to identify that before this question can be usefully answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectObjId` is anything you want it to be if you define to that naming a function, object, value...

e.g in Javascript (ECMAScript):

```
var selectObjId = document.getElementById('funnydiv');
```

---

P.S `ObjID` = JAVA

> JDK Doc(JAVA)
>   - class java.rmi.server..ObjID 
>   public final class ObjID extends Object implements Serializable 
>   Tree:java.lang.Object - java.rmi.server.ObjID
>   An ObjID is used to identify remote objects uniquely in a VM over time. Each identifier contains an object number and an address space identifier that is unique with respect to a specific host. An object identifier is assigned to a remote object when it is exported. If the property java.rmi.server.randomIDs is true, then the object number component (64 bits) of an ObjID created with the no argument constructor will contain a cryptographically strong random number.
>   - Constructor for class java.rmi.server.ObjID 
>   public ObjID ()
>   Generates a unique object identifier. If the property java.rmi.server.randomIDs is true, then the object number component (64 bits) of an ObjID created with the no argument constructor will contain a cryptographically strong random number.Since: JDK1.1
>   - Constructor for class java.rmi.server.ObjID 
>   public ObjID (int num)
>   Generates a "well-known" object ID. An object ID generated via this constructor will not clash with any object IDs generated via the default constructor.Parameters: num - a unique well-known object numberSince: JDK1.1

Comment: Thanks for your response, however in the code i have, selectObId is just referenced without having been declared or assigned any value sand the program works. Could it be that it was defined somewhere in a library? checked cordova.js, query.js and query-mobile.js but did not find it declared anywhere.

Comment: Unless if I am misunderstanding this line of code: var obj = $("#"+selectObjId)[0]; Does it declare and assign a value to selectObjId?

Comment: @user1210959 yes, but selectObjId needs to be defined elsewhere. Might be it's not inside the same file!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `selectObjId` is anything special in any library out there. It is probably just a mistake that it was never declared in the code you are using.

Javascript is very forgiving. It is quite possible that `selectObjId` has not been declared, but that your code still works. Depending on how you use it, it could also be the name of a function.

You can test by using `console.log(selectObjId)` to see what it prints out. You may need to have Firebug installed. Have a look at the [Firebug help](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Message_types) get more info on errors and warnings.

Remember to use your browser's error log when you are developing web pages.